# I have not API20 in android studio wizard in version 1.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded the new android studio and then I downloaded the important component according to Google. Now I have  problems in creating some projects.
For example **when I put the `Minimum SDK` equal to `22` or `23`. I can create my project successfully**. But when I put the `Minimum SDK` equal to `API19` or lower `APIs` I can not create project.Also Please note and see the following image. 
As you see I have not the `API20` in the options in the android studio wizard. Also please see the following images and they are the components in my `sdk` folder that they are installation in the `sdk` folder. I want when I put the `Minimum SDK` equal to `8`, I can crate a project and also for higher `APIs`.

Which essential items I have not in my `sdk` folder to create a project when I want to put the `Minimum SDK` equal to `8` ? Also in in first 
I said that I have not the `API20` in the options. Thank you in advances.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: also I have the `SDK platform` for api8 and api10 and api15 and api16 and api17 and api18 and api19 and api20

Comment: API Level is for wearable devices, you can download it from SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

`API Level 20` is for wearable devices, you can download it from SDK Manager & you have to select Wear Devices when you are going to create new project because it is not available for Phones & Tablets, but above API Level 20 are supported by Wear.